# Titanium: Sounds overlapping each other

Tags: audio, titanium

Sorry if it looks like a noob question, but i'm new to titanium so some concepts are foreign to me.

I have a script called entry.js which is called from details.js using require('entry.js').

Now within entry.js i play a sound, depending on what entry is selected.

```
    var player = Ti.Media.createSound({url:"/sounds/0"+e.id+".mp3"});
    player.play();
```

That part is ok. The problem is when i go back to the details screen, and select another entry, the new sound overlaps the old one.

So i need a global value or object that i can pass down to entry.js to make sure if the sound is playing or not.

But if i declare a global TI.Media object in details.js i get an error in entry.js:
Cant find variable player

So the question is, how do i detect in a sub javascript file that an instance of audio is already running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the audio is playing using the [`isPlaying()` method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Sound-method-isPlaying) or try to stop the playing music when you get back to the details screen. You can use [`stop()` method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Sound-method-stop) to stop the sound. It will stops playing the audio and resets the playback position to the beginning of the clip.

If you want to create a global variable or pass variable from one window to another, refer the following links

1. [Passing parameters from currentWindow to the new window in Titanium](http://sushmapandey.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/passing-parameters-from-currentwindow-to-the-new-window-in-titanium/)
2. [Passing variable between windows](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132078/passing-variable-between-window)

Comment: The isPlaying and stop dont work, since the player is defined at the sub page level and it does not detect it's playing.

Comment: I'm trying to pass parameters to the current window, but for the life of me it's not working. I keep getting undefined in the last window.

Comment: Try to create a app variable using Ti.App.Properties

Comment: I was using the kitchen sink example, and i'm guessing it was too segmented for it to work this way.
I'm placing all my code in one window now, and i have a feeling it will work.